# Cannot Register Custom Firebase FCM Service Worker With Webpack

Tags: javascript, firebase, webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging

Users can install our software anywhere, and we can’t guarantee a file will exist in the root of the domain. To solve this I register a custom service worker for FCM and everything works. No issues.

BUT! This only works on the local dev machine. On the production server webpack bundles everything to /dist/ and it cannot find the file to register the service worker.

So I am curious how to make the following code work with webpack.

Specifically:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/public/js/services/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
```

The above does not work with webpack as on the server it points to a non-existing file. The full process minus some code below.

```
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/public/js/services/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                this.messaging.getToken({serviceWorkerRegistration: registration, vapidKey: "CODE_HERE"}).then((currentToken) => {
                    //just some code here, removed to keep example smaller
                    }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    //just some code here, removed to keep example smaller
                });
            });
```

Comment: Did you have webpack.config ?

Comment: Yes I have that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
var ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin = require('serviceworker-webpack-plugin');
...
plugins: [
  new ServiceWorkerWepbackPlugin({
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'path/of/your_service_worker_file.js'),
  }),
],
...
```

Note: I'm not sure for the path value

Also you must register in main thread:

```
import runtime from 'serviceworker-webpack-plugin/runtime';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  const registration = runtime.register();
}
```